# Creating multiple object instances in for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, plotly

I am a bit struggling to understand this issue:
There are two plots with two different data passed in `y: data` as you can see at the first snippet below, instead of manually writing all the plots like in it, and since my original data have an arbitrary length (1, N), is there a clever way to define the plots in the for loop?

This is a dummy but working version.

```
Plotly.newPlot("plot", [{
  y: [getData()], // calls Math.random()
  type: 'line',
  line: {
    color: 'rgb(142, 142, 142)',
    width: 1
  },
}, {
  y: [getSData()], // calls Math.random()
  type: 'line',
  line: {
    color: 'rgb(142, 142, 142)',
    width: 1
  },
}

], layout, config);
```

I have tried to convert this snippet to with the for loop version, as I mentioned above my data has an arbitrary length [[1], ..., [N]].

```
let ob;
let PLOTS = Plotly.newPlot("plot", ob, layout, config)

// console.log(pos) => [Array(1)] 

for (let i = 0; i < pos.length; i++){
  ob.y = pos[I] // this spits an error
  ob.type = 'line'
  ob.color =  'rgb(142, 142, 142)'
}

let cnt = 0

setInterval(function(){
  Plotly.extendTraces('plot', {y: pos}, [...Array(pos.length).keys()]);

  cnt ++

  if (cnt > 128) {

    Plotly.relayout("plot", {
      xaxis: {
        range: [cnt-128, cnt]
      }
    });
  }

}, 20);
```

I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'y')` at `ob.y = pos[i]` I am not familiar with the language and the errors, therefore I might need a bit help. Thanks.

Comment: No idea what you are doing here `getData() && getSData()`. Please elaborate or simply include full code in your question.

Comment: Also instead of posting a bunch of code, it will be very helpful to debug "logical errors" if you explained your "intent" in plain language *along side* the code that does whatever. This will actually help *you* if you put your intent in code comments throughout the codified algorithm.

Comment: @GetSet I am a bit confused, when I try to explain in natural languages everyone asks the code? I did a hybrid version of it. Isn't it enough? I edited the code btw.

Comment: Ok well if you are "upgrading" someone else's code to suit your purposes, then state (1) a link to the original code (or include it in your question), and (2) how you want to modify it to suit your purposes in plain language, and ideally (3) your code attempt. A "logical error" requires "intent" to be able to debug.

Comment: You need to initialise `ob`as an object, like in `ob={}` and JavaScript distinguishes between `i` and `I` , so it should be `ob.y = pos[i]`.

Comment: That is if I or someone else can't easily figure out what you want to happen, then a communication gap exists for any solution to take place. This is when you might hear "can you post actual input and desired output".

Comment: @CarstenMassmann ```[I]``` was a typo that I have done here, Your suggestion worked. Thank you.